# What to do about a damaged stipple ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, plaster, lath-and-plaster

We have a stipple ceiling in our master bedroom, it appears to be lining paper over lathe & plaster with stipple/textured paint over that. We are concerned that it may have asbestos in it (we are getting it tested) and want to work out our options for it.

There are sections of the stipple that have been ripped off a little bit, and another section that has had some water damage from a dodgy flashing around a chimney which has been plastered over very roughly.

Should we cover this completely with plaster board, plaster it over completely to be smooth, or is there another option?

**Edit:** asbestos test results came back fine, no worries. Strip stipple, skim coat/plaster and paint?

Comment: Have you fixed the chimney flashing problem?  Certainly that would be the first thing to do, if you haven't.

Comment: @Grunthos the chimney is coming down and the roof will be patched over with new iron sheets, also I presume it had been fixed before we bought it - we didn't plaster up the ceiling

Comment: Wait for the asbestos results before bothering to make any plans.

Comment: No asbestos! Strip off lining paper and skim coat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was putting up batons on the ceiling and plasterboard over the top. We did this with the other wall which was questionable too.

Benefits here are that the finish is much better once finished, and it's decidedly less plastering than doing the entire wall.

The cost was likely higher than if we had plastered, but the end result was much better.

If we had decided to plaster over, the stipple paper would have come up relatively easily with a scraper and some elbow grease.